# How to set variables in a thymeleaf fragment?

Tags: thymeleaf

I understand Thymeleaf is made for rendering the views however, I just wanted to know if there is any way to set a variable may be in request scope in a Thymeleaf fragment?

I have a very large conditional expression that I have to repeat a lot of times across the application so it will be really helpful if I can set a variable in main layout then reuse it in all other child fragments.

I am aware of using a Spring interceptor and setting the variable in model but I prefer not to.

Please advise.

Thanks

Prash

Answer (score 36):

In the fragment template, define fragment with parameters:

```
<div th:fragment=”myfragment(myvariable)”>
    <p th:text=”${myvariable}”></p>
</div>
```

and in layout template, include fragment with that variable specified:

```
<div th:include=”template :: myfragment(${variable})”></div>
```

Then variable is passed to the fragment template.

Answer (score 13):

If you need the result of your expression only in the fragments you could use

```
th:with="var=${verylargeexpression}"
```

This creates a local variable which you can use everywhere within the dom element you defined it, including fragments.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div th:include="'path/your/file/' + ${variable}"></div>
```

The code above can use variables that you can choose to build the file path

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring MVC along with Thymeleaf, then you should be able to access any bean within thymeleaf template.

Just use expressions like this in global template ...

```
<span th:text="${beans.myBean.verylargeexpression}"></span>
```