# Thymeleaf - binding not working in a fragment

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

Not to be confused with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20622823/how-to-set-variables-in-a-thymeleaf-fragment)!

So, I'm trying to pass a bean in a Thymeleaf fragment and to bind its properties to some fields.

I.e. Let's say I have a fragment called `myFragment`:

```
<div th:fragment="myFragment(myBean)"> 
   <select class="selectpicker" th:field="${myBean.myProperty}">
        <option th:each="myProperty : ${myBean.myProperties}" th:value="${myProperty}" th:text="${myProperty}"></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And fragment is being called like this:

```
<div th:include="fragments/myFragment:: myFragment(myBean=${myBean})"> ... </div>
```

And that works for some reason because the name of the variable and the name of the bean are the same (`myBean`). But if the name of the bean is different, i.e. like this:

```
<div th:include="fragments/myFragment:: myFragment(myBean=${someOtherBean})"> ... </div>
```

I get an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'myBean' available as a request attribute
```

Everything works fine for other attributes like `th:text`, `th:href`... However, the exception occurs if I use `th:field` attribute (if I try to bind a property to some specific field). How to properly perform binding in this case?

Comment: But, your pattern works for me. Thanks. `<div th:include="fragments/init :: pagination (page=${listPage})"></div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to remove `th:field="..."` in select element and then add `th:selected="${<your_logic_when_is_selected>}"` in the `<option>` element.

One more thing. From my point of view you don't need the variable name declared in the `<div th:include="` element.